# Average daily move from implied volatility of risk reversal

Tags: options, implied-volatility, trading

I'm trying to understand an example in Euan Sinclair's Option Trading book. On page 239 he gives a risk slide and pnl from a long 30 delta put short 30 delta call position. He says the implied volatility is 50%. Then he claims that the average daily move on the underlying is 2.50. If the implied vol is 50% then the daily implied vol would be 50%/16=3.125% which would be an average daily move of 3.125 not 2.50. Is my logic wrong or am I not understanding what he is saying? The equations he refers to are 8.7 and 8.10 which I have also provided pictures of. These equations seem to have to do with deriving a bound on the convexity in implied vol (how is this relevant to the example?).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The average daily move is actually $\sigma (2/\pi)^(0.5)$ which is indeed 2.50 in your example.  I don’t see how this is related to the equations.

Comment: how do you derive that average daily move formula and how does it differ from the daily implied volatility?

Comment: I was under the impression that if we had a 50% IV then the daily IV is 3.12% and therefore the underlying is expected to move by that percentage per day.

Comment: It I think the IV represents the square root of the Expected squared move, but if you want the expected value of the absolute value of the daily move,  you get the sqrt (2/pi) factor